# SwiftUI - Returning an opaque type in a protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

Currently, I have a protocol `Media` which has the method `displaySummary() -> some View`. The problem is, an opaque type cannot be returned in a protocol, as far as I know.

```
protocol Media {
  func displaySummary() -> some View
}
```

The implementation code looks like the following:

```
final class Playlist: Media {
func displaySummary() -> some View {
  return HStack {
    Text("Summary")
      .padding(.all)
      .background(Color.black)
  }
}
```

And in the ContentView, I have the following:

```
let media: Media = Playlist()

var body: some View {
  ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    media.displaySummary()
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

Here is variant using protocol `associatedtype`, actually SwiftUI native approach, if we see in its auto-generated module. This allows to avoid type-erasure wrappers and use view directly.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

#### Update: added ViewBulider, re-tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
protocol Media {
    associatedtype Summary : View
    func displaySummary() -> Self.Summary
}

final class Playlist: Media, Identifiable {
    @ViewBuilder
    func displaySummary() -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Summary")
                .padding(.all)
                .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

struct PlaylistView: View {
    let playlist = Playlist()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            playlist.displaySummary()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this implementation, you are instantiating a Playlist object without constraining it to a protocol, which gives an error if you do. 

I.E. `let playlist: Media = Playlist()`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using a type-erasure.

```
protocol Media {
 func displaySummary() -> AnyView
}
```

Simple wrap the opaque View in AnyView:

```
final class Playlist: Media {
 func displaySummary() -> AnyView {
   return AnyView(HStack {
     Text("Summary")
       .padding(.all)
       .background(Color.black))
     })
   }
 }
```

Comment: I've ended up with the same implementation, but I'm really concerned about possible performance issues.